# A bit of math and logic

Tags: python, math, logic

So I have this problem here:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9.
>   The sum of these multiples is 23.
>   Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

And I wrote this here:

```
def multiples(num, below):
    counter = 1
    z = 0
    while True:
        x = num * counter
        if x < below:
            z += x
        else:
            break
        counter += 1
    return z
below = 1000
print "Multiples of 3: " + str(multiples(3, below))
print "Multiples of 5: " + str(multiples(5, below))
print "Added: " + str(multiples(3, below) + multiples(5, below))
```

If I set `below` to 10 I get the right answer, 23

```
Multiples of 3: 18
Multiples of 5: 5
Added: 23
```

But when I set it to 1000 I get this:

```
Multiples of 3: 166833
Multiples of 5: 99500
Added: 266333
```

And this is supposedly wrong, is there something I'm not getting?

Comment: This would be Euler Project number 1 would it? http://projecteuler.net/problem=1

Comment: Pre much. I failed on the first one xD. Nah Im doing okay now, a few through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you need to remove multiples of 15 once below 1000, because it will be duplicated in both 3 & 5.. Which does not happens for below 10..

```
Multiple of 3 & 5  = (multiple of 3 + multiple of 5 - multiple of 15)
```

So, you can use a `Set` to store those multiples, to remove the duplicate..

Answer (score 3):

A Pythonic way to do this is use list-comprehension (or generator-comprehension):

```
sum( n for n in xrange(1,1000) 
        if n % 3 == 0 or n%5 == 0 )
```

.

The problem that you were having is that you were including multiples of fifteen (those for which `n%3==0 and n%5==0`) twice, doing this in one list avoids this type of error.

Comment: For generator expressions used as arguments, you don't need the additional parentheses: you can just write `sum(n for n in xrange(1000) if n%3==0 or n%5==0)`. Apart from that, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
multiples_of_3 = range(0,1000,3)
multiples_of_5 = range(0,1000,5)
sum_of_multiples = sum(set(itertools.chain(multiples_of_3, multiples_of_5)))
```

OR

```
multiples_of_3 = range(0,1000,3)
multiples_of_5 = range(0,1000,5)
multiples_of_15 = set(range(0,1000,15))
sum_of_multiples = sum(set(i for i in itertools.chain(multiples_of_3, multiples_of_5) if i not in multiples_of_15))
```